# ASP.NET MVC 3 - detect if dirty for multiple checkboxes on multiple pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have a long list of items and I'd like to display them to the user with a checkbox next to each item representing whether the item is on or off.  Because there are many items, the items are display using paging.

When a page is loaded, a checkbox is checked if the item is on.  The user can page through the items, check/uncheck the checkboxes.

I want to enable the submit button only when there is a change of the items' states.  What is the optimal way to detect if the list of items is in dirty state when the user pages through the list and makes changes.

Comment: @danludwig - knockout will only help with the part of the problem

Comment: @MystereMan you may be right, I glazed over the part about paging while making changes. However if paging is done on the client instead of the server (ajax), can't you just get away with using observables to compute whether a checkbox is dirty / submit button should be enabled?

Comment: @danludwig - you could use observables in place of a hidden field, yes.  But that won't help for a non-js based solution.

Answer (score 1):

How you would do this is different depending on if you are doing page refreshes for scrolling or ajax.

If you are just reloading the page with the new page information, then you will need some kind of state to keep track of the previously selected items.  This could be done either in Session, or in a temporary table.  A temporary table would survive a session reset, and would work in a server farm scenario.

In any event, either your page postsback on checkbox click, or you post on next page (In either case you want to do a [post-redirect-get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)).  When the page refreshes, you need to return an indication of whether the collection is dirty or not, and enable the submit button.

Be aware that a user could walk away in mid-selection and come back half an hour later or something.  If their login is still valid, and you use session, session may have recycled.

If you're doing Ajax, then you need to keep a running list of changes, so that if the user later unselects them you can disable the submit button again.  You would keep this list in a hidden field, and either ajax post each checkbox as it happens to a temporary table, or you could just keep the running total in the hidden and apply the changes when submit is called.  Your hidden field would probably contain a list of id's that you have changed (either checked or unchecked).  And when the field is empty, disable the button and when it's not, enable it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You have many good points.  I'll see how they work out for me.